# Looking for a working VBscript to pull back the Office 2010 Key

Tags: scripting, vbscript, ms-office

I work for a service provider and have custom VBscripts on all our supported machines that report back the machines Windows and Office keys. We found that since Office 2010 the method to return keys hasn't worked. From Googling I have found many scripts for Office 2010 but none of them seem to work. What I am looking for is a script that gets the Product Name and Product Key for Office 2010 and puts them into a variable (or two).

I have looked everywhere and googled till my fingers are bleeding but none of the ones I have found have worked. They either return nothing or the wrong key on multiple machines.

Comment: It's probably in the registry somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

From your post it sounds like the scripts you downloaded works on some machines, but not on others, is that correct? If so, I'd check if this might be due to 32bit vs 64bit since there are some differences in registry access. If this is the case you might be able to use the scripts you've found, but just adjust them to look in different location depending on OS.

Otherwise, if you'd be able to use an external executable, then there are plenty of tools on the internet to do this, [this one](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) says that they have a command line interface (I've not tried it), that you might be able to automate from your script.

Otherwise I'd suggest downloading [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and have that running logging any writes to the registry while you install and register a copy of Office 2010 on the various versions of Windows that you support, this should give you the registry location, and then you could hopefully find the decryption algorithm somewhere.